# Non-clean shut down and dirty log for neo4j

Tags: neo4j, jrubyonrails

I have been keep getting this error while rebuilding index for my production db:

`org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager commit
 ** [out :: XXX] SEVERE: Commit failed
 ** [out :: XXX] java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /bbp/www/pally/shared/db/neo4j-production/index/lucene/node/User_exact/_2i.fnm (No such file or directory)`

and

`Dirty log: /bbp/www/pally/releases/20130213131212/db/neo4j-production/index/lucene.log.1 now closed. Recovery will be started automatically next time it is opened.`

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Comment: can you get on the server and check whether the path `/bbp/www/pally/` really exists? i got a feeling this is not an absolute path and should be rather `bbp/www/pally/` or `/home/pally/.../bbp/www/pally/`

Comment: Hi @ulkas...path is totally correct..i have checked it..

Comment: Does it happen right away when starting or rarely in the middle of production? It looks like a Lucene problem, but I don't recognize it as such. Have you got any other processes touching those files?

Comment: @MattiasPersson it happens just after deployment and there is no other process touching these files...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm perhaps the index shut down or crashed in a bad state. That's extremely rare though. Would it be possible to delete that index from disk, deleting it from the neo4j database and rebuild it by looping through all user nodes again?

Comment: I have been doing the same thing whenever that error occurs...but after every deployment this error occurs..